# такая ошибка TypeError: Database() takes no arguments

Tags: python, telegram

Пытаюсь разобраться с базой для telegram бота.

```
db=Database('database.db')
@dp.message_handler(commands['start'])
async def start(message:types.Message):
    if (not db.user_exists(message.from_user.id)):
        db.add_user(message.from_user.id)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,'Укажите ваш ник')
    else:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Вы уже зарегестрированы',reply_markup=nav.mainMenu)

@dp.message_handler()
async def bot_message(message: types.Message):
    if message.chat.type=='private':
        if message.text=='Профиль':
            pass
        else:
            if db.get_signup(message.from_user.id)=='setnickname':
                if(len(message.text)>15):
                    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,'Никнейм не должен превышать 15 символов')
                elif '@' in message.text or '/' in message.text:
                    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,'Вы ввели запрещенный символ')
                else:
                    db.set_nickname(message.from_user.id, message.text)
                    db.set_signup(message.from_user.id, 'done')
                    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Регистарция прошла успешно',reply_markup=nav.mainMenu)
            else:
                await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Что?')
```

после запуска, выводит такую ошибку.

TypeError: Database() takes no arguments

почему так не понимаю. делал все по гайду

код базы данных

```
import sqlite3


class Database:
    def __unit__(self, db_file):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def add_user(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'users' ('user_id') VALUES (?)", (user_id,))# добавление пользователя


    def user_exists(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT*FROM 'users' WHERE 'user_id'=?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
            return bool(len(result))

    def set_nickname(self, user_id, nickname):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("UPDATE 'users' SET 'nickname'=? WHERE 'user_id'=?", (nickname, user_id,))

    def get_signup(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT 'signup' FROM 'users' WHERE 'user_id'=?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
            for row in result:
                signup = str(row[0])
            return signup

    def set_signup(self, user_id, signup):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("UPDATE 'users' SET 'signup'=? WHERE 'user_id'=?", (signup, user_id))
```

Ошибку я исправил. теперь код такой.

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
bot = Bot(token=TOKEN_API)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
db=Database('database.db')
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message:types.Message):
    if (not db.user_exists(message.from_user.id)):
        db.add_user(message.from_user.id)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,'Укажите ваш ник')
    else:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Вы уже зарегестрированы',reply_markup=nav.mainMenu)

@dp.message_handler()
async def bot_message(message: types.Message):
    if message.chat.type=='private':
        if message.text=='Профиль':
            pass
        else:
            if db.get_signup(message.from_user.id)=='setnickname':
                if(len(message.text)>15):
                    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,'Никнейм не должен превышать 15 символов')
                elif '@' in message.text or '/' in message.text:
                    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,'Вы ввели запрещенный символ')
                else:
                    db.set_nickname(message.from_user.id, message.text)
                    db.set_signup(message.from_user.id, 'done')
                    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Регистарция прошла успешно',reply_markup=nav.mainMenu)
            else:
                await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Что?')

if __name__ == 'main':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

для базы данных

import sqlite3

```
class Database:
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def add_user(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'users' ('user_id') VALUES (?)", (user_id,))# добавление пользователя


    def user_exists(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT*FROM 'users' WHERE 'user_id'=?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
            return bool(len(result))

    def set_nickname(self, user_id, nickname):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("UPDATE 'users' SET 'nickname'=? WHERE 'user_id'=?", (nickname, user_id,))

    def get_signup(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT 'signup' FROM 'users' WHERE 'user_id'=?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
            for row in result:
                signup = str(row[0])
            return signup

    def set_signup(self, user_id, signup):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("UPDATE 'users' SET 'signup'=? WHERE 'user_id'=?", (signup, user_id))
```

вот что на выходе

Process finished with exit code 0

ошибка была тут

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
        executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

теперь ругается

```
def get_signup(self, user_id):
    with self.connection:
        result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT 'signup' FROM 'users' WHERE 'user_id'=?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
        for row in result:
            signup = str(row[0])
        return signup
```

такой ошибкой

```
return signup
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'signup' referenced before assignment
```

если сдвинуть вправо return signup
не ругается, но бот на ввод ника отвечает что?, ну и базу данных не записывает ник.

Comment: Тут фигня `def __unit__(self, db_file):` конструктор должен быть `__init__`

Comment: не совсем понял

Comment: всю строку надо заменить?

Comment: `__unit__` поменять на `__init__`

Comment: так теперь после запуска почти сразу завершает работу. Без ошибок. будто весь код это print(''), только ничего не выводит

Comment: Приводите минимальный пример, так-то не знаю что вы там накодили :)

Comment: Я исправил unit на init, и знак равенства где пропустил поставил  на выходе только Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Текущий ваш код не выполняет какую-либо полезную нагрузку, поэтому нечему там работать. Для бота кроме объявления функций-обработчиков еще есть строка, которая его запускает и в вашем коде ее я не вижу. Поэтому и пишу про минимальный пример

Comment: 'if __name__ == 'main':'  
'    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)' оно?

Comment: Ага, но приводите код в вопросе. И уберите из примера токен бота

Comment: все теперь в вопосе пример

Comment: `if __name__ == 'main':` тут неправильно, там должно быть `if __name__ == '__main__':`. При явном запуске скрипта, а не при импорте, в `__name__` переменной будет именно `__main__`

Comment: спасибо разобрался

Comment: вылезла другая проблема, если коротко, то бот пропускает шаги, и сразу переходит к последней строке кода в хэндлере,  'await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Что?')' и не записывает ник в базу данных

Comment: и еще момент один, кнопки не вылезают

Comment: Оформите ответ по ранее возникшим проблемам как собственный. А по новым проблемам задавайте их как новые вопросы :)

Comment: хорошо вот здесь задал новый вопрос. с кнопками я решил проблему. остальные остались  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1488330/%d0%a2%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-signup-referenced-before-assign